# Show mobile nav on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

As my first attempt for this question wasn't that good, I will try to give a better explanation.

I'm using a cms called LumApps. I only have the option to add javascript, JQuery, or CSS. I can not edit the source code directly.

My goal is to use the build in mobile navigation on all resolutions as it has some functionality requested by my client.

The issue: The HTML for the mobile navigation only gets inserted in the DOM when the resolution / browser width is under 1024px. Therefore I can not use it as desktop navigation.

I have already changed the css to modify the mobile navigation to use it as desktop navigation.

So at this point when I load the page the hamburger icon is visible but when I click on it nothing happens. But when I manually resize my browser window once, so that the browser window width is below 1024px, the hamburger icon will be clickable the mobile navigation will show.

The code of the mobile navigation

```
<ng-include src="'/client/front- 
office/modules/layout/modules/app/views/partials/mobile-sidebar.html'" ng- 
if="app.displayMobileSidebar &amp;&amp; 
!app.ConfigTheme.HAS_CUSTOM_MOBILE_SIDEBAR"></ng-include>
```

I have tried triggering the window resize event in the console with following code:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

I think this could be solved if I could somehow fake a window resize but it must be under 1024px. The code I mentioned above should be doing that but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Just hide the code using media queries : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Do you know about the feature in DevTools to emulate mobile devices?

Comment: @Treast I'm not trying to hide anything, I need the code for the mobile navigation to be loaded in the html on all resolutions not only under 1024px. So that I can use it as desktop navigtion.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I know those tools, but using those would only solve the issue for me, not for all the users visting the site. I need some way to trick chrome that the resolution is under 1024px so that angular will insert the code for the mobile navigation.

Comment: I assumed you were just trying to test the code to see how it looks on mobile devices, not change it for everyone.

Comment: That is a question you could resolve on your own!

Comment: "My goal is to use mobile navigation as desktop navigation." can you specify better this phrase, thanks? Can you clarify better your question?

Comment: @LXG I have edited my post, not sure if it's more clear now. Please let me know which extra info you need. ty.

Comment: "The HTML for the mobile navigation only gets inserted in the DOM when the resolution / browser width is under 1024px". This is a problem; browsers can be resized so your page needs to be able to switch between mobile and desktop view without changing the DOM if at all possible. Make sure that all necessary elements are in the DOM at all times then use CSS media queries to select which ones are visible.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you reduce the question to its minimal form without the background. However there are a number of strange things about your situation (like the html changing based on the screen size!) so it's not clear what that minimal form is. You could get around this by telling the client to resize the window to smaller than 1024px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use devtools to resize to mobile device.
**Firefox**
[image]

**Chrome**
[image]

After this you can click with the mouse at the edges an resize to your desire.

Comment: Hi, I think I did not form my question well. My goal is to use the mobile navigation as desktop navigation. So I need this code for the mobile navigation to be loaded at all times for every user visiting the site. 

I need some way to make chrome believe the resolution is under 1024px so that angular will insert the code for the mobile navigation. This code is not available on page load on larger resolutions.